# ARP Spoofing succeeded only partially

Tags: man-in-the-middle, chrome, arp-spoofing

I have done arp spoofing to my phone using scapy and detected duplicate ips in the arp protocol with wireshark.
However, access to websites using chrome app was blocked, but youtube and onedrive apps can be accessed normally.
Can you think of anything that might have caused it?

Comment: Yes, certificate pinning and the use of HTTPS (which is designed to prevent this sort of attack ...). What was the message when Chrome was blocked?

Comment: Welcome to the community. I might be thinking it might an IP conflict as well.

Comment: @schroeder: There was no message. The top progress bar is slightly advanced and the page is not displayed.